# opencv I have problems with the next class of android?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have problems with this class. The problem I have is that one of my classes does not work correctly as it should when running on android. The application stops because it can not convert the image. Please someone who can help me.

package com.example.jorge.demo.object_recog;

```
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;

import org.opencv.video.Video;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Utilities {

    public static ArrayList<File> getJPGFiles(File dir) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".jpg");
            }
        });

        Arrays.sort(files);
        ArrayList<File> jpgFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (File file : files) {
            jpgFiles.add(file);
        }
        return jpgFiles;
    }

// How can I replace this class. ArrayList <Mat> getImageMats (ArrayList <File>imageFiles)


    public static ArrayList<Mat> getImageMats(ArrayList<File> imageFiles) {
        ArrayList<Mat> imageMats = new ArrayList<Mat>();

        for (File image : imageFiles) {

//What is failing is what I commented. There is another solution for this problem that I have

            //Mat fullSizeTrainImg = Highgui.imread(image.getPath());
            //Mat resizedTrainImg = new Mat();
            //Imgproc.resize(fullSizeTrainImg, resizedTrainImg, new Size(640, 480), 0, 0, Imgproc.INTER_CUBIC);
            //imageMats.add(resizedTrainImg);

        }

        return imageMats;

    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getFileNames(ArrayList<File> imageFiles) {
        ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (File image : imageFiles) {
            fileNames.add(image.getName().substring(0, image.getName().lastIndexOf(".")));
        }

        return fileNames;
    }

    public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```